# Select2 more filter in Django

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

i have this code below, where i'm using [Select2](https://select2.org/) in my select component, it's working fine, as i'm writing it's looking, but i've already searched the internet to find examples of how to customize the query set that runs in the widget, some help ?

[select2 works very well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/var8k.png)

```
class ConsumidorWidget(s2forms.ModelSelect2Widget):
search_fields = [
    "nome__icontains",
    "email__icontains",
]

class ConsumoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Consumo
    fields = ('id', 'consumidor', 'mesconsumo', 'anoconsumo', 'valorapagar', 'valorhidrometro',
              'dataleitura', 'datamissao', 'datavencimento', 'foipago',)

    exclude = ('bairro',)
    mesconsumo = forms.ChoiceField()

    widgets = {
        "consumidor": ConsumidorWidget,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ModelChoiceField`:

```
consumidor = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Consumo.objects.all(),
    widget=ConsumidorWidget)
```

Or you can try overriding the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['consumidor'].queryset = Consumo.objects.all()
```